# Firestore multiple timed batch commits hangs without any response

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, batch-processing

I have been having an issue with Firestore batch commits trying to update a collection of documents regularly, or when trying to write a large set of data. Firestore seems to just freeze and won't send a response. In both cases, recommendations for maximum batch size (500) and document size is respected. Using cron-jobs, for example, the commits run successfully for some time before stopping altogether without any error trace.

For example, the code below gets executed for 6 times in a row before starting to misbehave.

```js
public updateCoins = async () =>{
  const markets = await this.getMarkets('usd')
  const maxCount = Math.round(markets.length/this.FB_BATCH_SIZE) + 1
  for(let i=0; i< maxCount; i++){
    const marketBatch = markets.slice(i*this.FB_BATCH_SIZE, (i+1)*this.FB_BATCH_SIZE  > markets.length ? markets.length : (i+1)*this.FB_BATCH_SIZE)
    const batchCoins = this.fbService.db.batch()
    marketBatch.map((entry)=>{
    const coin = this.mapCoin(entry)
      if(coin){
        const coinRef = this.coinsCol.doc(coin.id);
                    batchCoins.set(coinRef,coin,{merge:true})
      }
    }) 
            
    await batchCoins.commit()
    .then(()=>{
      console.log('Commited coins batch update')
    }).catch((_e)=>{
      console.log('Exception saving coins',_e)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: I've tested the script on both my machine (OSX) and on a server @DougStevenson